# SQL Return default values if no rows returned

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've got a SQL script which returns a result set, the requirement is to return a default result set with default values if the below script does not yield any results. It should have the same column names as the below script

```
 -- Return final results
    SELECT  
        p.worked                                                                           [AccountsWorked],
        p.rcmade                                                                       [RPC's],
        p.obtained                                                                             [PTPCount],
        p.amount                                                                          [PTPValue], 
                                                                                                [PreviousDayPTPValue]

    FROM
        @tab_performance p JOIN
        dbo.user usr ON
            (p.usr_code = usr.usr_code) JOIN
        dbo.team tme ON 
            (tme.tme_id = usr.tme_id)   
            AND p.usr_code = @usr_code
```

I need to return a default result set if no rows are returned. So all the columns should be returned with NULL's or any default value.

I have tried conditional select statements without any luck, I have also tried the @@ROWCOUNT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a `union all` select to your existing query with default values like this:

```
<your existing query>

union all

select null accounts_worked, null right_contacts_made, null ppts_obtained .....
where not exists(
select *
from @tab_performance p JOIN
        dbo.TR_USR_User usr ON
            (p.usr_code = usr.usr_code) JOIN
        dbo.TR_TME_Team tme ON 
            (tme.tme_id = usr.tme_id)   
            AND p.usr_code = @usr_code
)
```

The `where` clause could be further simplified, if your `inner joins` don't filter out any rows from `@tab_performance`:

```
<your existing query>

union all 

select null accounts_worked, null right_contacts_made, null ppts_obtained .....
where not exists(
select *
from @tab_performance
where usr_code = @usr_code
)
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do it with **WITH** and **UNION ALL**

```
Drop  table if exists #test
create table #test (
    Column1 int null,
    Column2 varchar(50) null
);

--INSERT INTO [#test] (Column1,Column2)
--VALUES        
--        (1, 'test'),
--        (2,'test2'),
--        (3,'test3');

WITH qry AS (
   select Column1, Column2 from #test
)
select * from qry
UNION ALL
select NULL as Colum1, null as Column2 where (select COUNT(*) from qry) = 0
```